# Images in NSButton not showing up?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, nsbutton

I've tried that several times, and it seems there is some bug with that (Xcode 4.3.3 - OS X 10.7) :

- Put an `NSButton` in Interface Builder
- Set it to 'Image Only'
- Drag'n'drop a system icon (e.g. `NSAddTemplate`)

But the icon fails to show (while I'm perfectly able to see icons when they're not system icons, but added by me).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I've just tried, it works in a weird way.
Try to set *image* and *alternate* in the NSButton inspector.
Pick the images from the drop-down menu directly instead of drag-dropping it.

It works but it's just a workaround...

Answer (score 2):

Alternate answer: Make sure the image files are included in the Copy Bundle Resources phase for your target (especially if you have multiple targets in your Xcode project). There is no build-time error or warning if you specify an image that is not in your bundle.  (There is a runtime warning).